# How to extract data by occurance of values in a column which maps multiple times in another colums?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as follows:

```
Data    Items   Key
SD1     ABX2    9
SD2     ABX2    10
SD3     ABX2    23
SD1     CAB2    sd
SD1     ABX2    km
SD1     CAB2    kj
SD5     TND     lo
SD9     TNK     gf
SD7     SDK     bf
SD11    CAB2    lo
SD1     TND     78
SD3     TND     nm
```

I want to filter based on values in the `Items` column which is found across minimum three different `Data`. The expected output is:

```
Data    Items   Key
SD1     ABX2    9
SD2     ABX2    10
SD3     ABX2    23
SD1     ABX2    km
SD5     TND     lo
SD1     TND     78
SD3     TND     nm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform('nunique')` to count the number of data each item appears, then use boolean indexing to filter:

```
df[df.groupby('Items').Data.transform('nunique')>=3]
```

Output:

```
   Data Items Key
0   SD1  ABX2   9
1   SD2  ABX2  10
2   SD3  ABX2  23
4   SD1  ABX2  km
6   SD5   TND  lo
10  SD1   TND  78
11  SD3   TND  nm
```